# Cursor only returning one value / last value

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite, android-cursor

I am really stuck as I have a cursor that retrieves values from the database but the cursor only returns the last value. I need the cursor to retrieve all values so I can display them all later on. Is there any way as I can return all the data stored through the cursor?

An Example as to whats happening. Eg Click on Button 1 and stores 1 perfectly but once I click on Button 2 and add 1. Button 1 data is not return or retrieved.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Execute

The first Cursor is goes through to check all the stored items.

```
public void exectute() {
    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Cursor c = TrackerDb.getStoredItems(getApplicationContext());
            if (c != null) {
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    WorkoutDetails details = null;
                    //if (details != null) mWorkoutDetailsList.add(details);
                    do {
                        //if (details != null) mWorkoutDetailsList.add(details);
                        WorkoutDetails temp = getWorkoutFromCursor(c);
                        //if (details != null) mWorkoutDetailsList.add(details);
                        if (details == null) {
                            details = temp;
                            continue;
                        }
                        //if (details != null) mWorkoutDetailsList.add(details);
                        if (isSameDay(details.getWorkoutDate(), temp.getWorkoutDate())) {
                            //if (details != null) mWorkoutDetailsList.add(details);
                            if (DBG) Log.d(LOG_TAG, "isSameDay().. true");
                            //details.add(temp);
                        } else {
                            mWorkoutDetailsList.add(details);
                            details = temp;
                        }
                       // if (details != null) mWorkoutDetailsList.add(details);
                    } while (c.moveToNext());
                    if (details != null) mWorkoutDetailsList.add(details);

                    if (DBG)
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "AsyncTask: list size " + mWorkoutDetailsList.size());

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mWorkoutsAdapter.updateList(mWorkoutDetailsList);
                        }
                    });
                }


                c.close();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Get Stored Items Code

This is the code which the excute class calls and where the cursor only returns one value.

```
public static Cursor getStoredItems(Context context) {
    DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    SQLiteDatabase db  = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] projection = {ID, TIME, TYPE, DURATION, DATE, POINT};
    String orderBy = TIME + " DESC";
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, projection, null, null, null, null, orderBy);
    return cursor;
}
```

Array

This is the array code where i want the cursor to store its values based on type.

```
private WorkoutDetails getWorkoutFromCursor(Cursor c) {
    long time = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(TrackerDb.TIME));
    int type = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(TrackerDb.TYPE));
    int duration = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(TrackerDb.DURATION));
    int point = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(TrackerDb.POINT));

    int totalMoney = MoneyActivity.Money.values().length;
    int[] points = new int[totalMoney];

    int totalActivities = MeditationTrackerActivity.ACTIVITIES.values().length;
    int[] durations = new int[totalActivities];
    if (type < totalActivities) {
        durations[type] = duration;
    }

    if( type == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < totalMoney; i++) {
            points[type] = point;
        }
    }
    else if ( type == 1) {
        for ( int ii = 0; ii < totalMoney; ii++) {
            points[type] = point;
        }
    }
    else if ( type == 2) {
        for ( int iii = 0; iii < totalMoney; iii++) {
            points[type] = point;
        }
    }

    return new WorkoutDetails(time, durations, points);
}
```

Get Workout From Cursor Code

```
private static WorkoutDetails getWorkoutFromCursor(Cursor c) {
    long time = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(TrackerDb.TIME));
    int type = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(TrackerDb.TYPE));
    int duration = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(TrackerDb.DURATION));
    String date = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TrackerDb.DATE));

    int point = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(TrackerDb.POINT));
    int[] durations = new int[MeditationTrackerActivity.ACTIVITIES.values().length];
    durations[type] = duration;

    int[] points = new int[MoneyActivity.Money.values().length];
    points[type] = point;
    return new WorkoutDetails(time, durations, date, points);
}
```

Comment: I believe you are adding details to workoutdetailsList only  after exeuting the loop,so only the last data is getting stored. Add if (details != null) mWorkoutDetailsList.add(details); inside the loop

Comment: @p.mathew13 I have tried to add the line you suggested but still not working and only returning last value.  Maybe this example might help better.  Eg Click on Button 1 and stores 1 perfectly but once i click on Button 2 and add 1. Button 1 data is not return or retrieved.